# right-left-left-right distribution of floats or elements in columns

Tags: css

I have four block elements (of type `aside`, they're widgets in a Wordpress sidebar). In a narrow container (e.g. on a mobile phone) they are stacked one above the other:

```
one
two
three
four
```

In a broad container (viewed on desktop) I want them in two columns:

```
+-------+------+
| two   | one  |
|       +------+
|       | four |
+-------+      |
| three |      |
+-------+      |
        |      |
        +------+
```

Please note the order!

All elements are of unequal, varying height. All elements have the same fixed width, which is half that of their parent element.

Floats leave an ugly gap:

```
+-------+------+
| two   | one  |
|       +------+
|       |         <= I do not want this gap!
+-------+------+
| three | four |
+-------+      |
        |      |
        |      |
        |      |
        +------+
```

#### How can I make this work *without gaps between elements?*

*Sorry for not providing a working code sample, but I'm on my mobile phone for the next few days and typing is a pain.*

Comment: Sounds like another question that needs [**masonry.js**](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to solve it.

Comment: Do you want elements "two" and "one" to have the same height? similarly for "three" and "four"?

Comment: @MarcAudet No, all elements are filled dynamically and their individual height does not correlate with the height of the other elemenzs.

Comment: Do you want the two columns to have the same width?

Comment: Final question, do you care about the HTML? or anything as long as it works?

Comment: @MarcAudet Sorry for taking so long to answer. Was swimming with the kids. Yes, all the elements are half the width of the parent element, which has a fixed width. Do I care about the HTML? Huh? I don't know, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done if you are willing to add a wrapping block element around your 2nd and 3rd content blocks.

In my code below, I added the wrapper `.left-col`.  For a wide page, (I added the class `.wide` to trigger the effect, but you can use media queries), set `width: 50%` and `float: left` for `.left-col`, and add some padding to the right if you want some whitespace.  To keep the math simple, also add `box-sizing: border-box`.

What this does is keep the two blocks `.col2` and `.col3' in a single column to the left with normal top/bottom margins (no large gaps).

For `.col1`, set the width to 50% and `float: right`, so this element will position itself to the right of the `.left-col` block, thus starting a second column.

Finally, for `.col4`, this block is actually not floated, just part of the regular content flow.  Add `overflow: auto` to prevent the text from wrapping around the left floated block, and then `margin-top: 10px` to preserve the margin with respect to the bottom edge of the floated `.col1` block.

I tested this on the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome and IE on a Win7 PC, and everything seems to work okay.

If you remove `.wide` class, you will see that you get the vertical layout that you need for a smaller screen.

```css
.panel {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
div[class^="col"] {
    background-color: beige;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.wide .left-col {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wide .col1 {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
.wide .col4 {
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel wide">
    <div class="col1">1 Donec adipiscing, lorem non euismod venenatis, diam orci tincidunt magna, ut interdum magna arcu vel elit. Nunc molestie lacus non urna eleifend mattis. Praesent ipsum nulla, tempor malesuada lacinia quis, elementum et tellus.</div>
    <div class="left-col">
        <div class="col2">2 Vestibulum arcu lectus, venenatis non aliquam a, imperdiet nec neque. Sed facilisis, est eu sollicitudin ullamcorper, urna erat tincidunt lectus, laoreet pulvinar velit turpis sit amet ligula. Cras iaculis elit et augue aliquet ullamcorper. Sed metus sem, dictum mollis adipiscing lacinia, placerat at sapien. Mauris leo libero, consequat vel ultrices at, adipiscing imperdiet justo. Vestibulum vestibulum gravida nunc vel varius. Cras id velit venenatis dui ultrices vestibulum. Phasellus dapibus rutrum nulla, at malesuada elit pellentesque at. Vestibulum sit amet elit sapien.</div>
        <div class="col3">3 Morbi consequat, purus nec suscipit luctus, ipsum felis pulvinar nulla, a pulvinar nunc nibh sed nulla. Donec ac pellentesque lacus. Nullam magna velit, pellentesque ut sodales sit amet, tristique id elit.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col4">4 Mauris erat tellus, dapibus sit amet congue eu, euismod at eros. Ut quis tincidunt ante. Aenean rhoncus lacinia odio, et sodales massa accumsan eu. Pellentesque bibendum volutpat varius. Proin mauris massa, sollicitudin eget elementum luctus, facilisis a lectus. Sed eu lorem ac arcu cursus mollis vitae eget risus. Integer quis quam sed magna tristique consequat tristique eu sem. Duis in eros nec ligula varius placerat. Nam commodo tellus vel lorem aliquet sed scelerisque magna porta. Donec vulputate interdum mauris ac euismod. Donec facilisis lectus nec tellus sollicitudin lobortis. Nulla nulla lorem, dapibus vitae posuere eu, volutpat eu tortor. In sollicitudin ante quis augue tempus tristique.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, I see where you were going with your questions. I'd prefer not to add that container, but this seems the easiest way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with margin, it's pretty weird.
This is a cross browser solution, if you don't need to support IE8, you can use `nth-child()` instead of the adjacent sibling selector. To work with unequal heights, you need to clear float at the start of the second row:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
  width: 80%;
  outline: 1px solid #f0f;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

li:first-child {
  margin-left: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

li:first-child + li {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-left: -100%;
  height: 50px
}

li:first-child + li + li {
  clear: left;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

li:first-child + li + li + li {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

**Example**

http://codepen.io/goshdarnheck/pen/rVeXZy

Comment: Does this still apply if **"All elements are of unequal, varying height."** as stated by the OP?

Comment: @Paulie_D yes, I think you need to know the width

Comment: @Paulie_D I've updated the question with the CSS and Codepen showing a responsive version, with percent widths.

Comment: This leaves gaps between columns. The gaps are what made me ask this question, but unfortunately I forgot to explicitly mention that in my question, so +1 for providing a working answer for the question as I asked it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use nth-child(n+n) and clear.

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 3px green;
  padding:0;
  float:left;
  margin:0.5em;
}

li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px turquoise;
}
li:first-of-type , 
li:nth-child(4n+1)/* if more than 4 li to keep going*/{
  float:right
}
li:nth-child(2n+1) {
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="height:30px;">one</li>
  <li style="height:90px;">two</li>
  <li style="height:50px;">three</li>
  <li style="height:40px;">four</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li style="height:30px;">one</li>
  <li style="height:90px;">two</li>
  <li style="height:50px;">three</li>
  <li style="height:40px;">four</li>
  <li style="height:30px;">five</li>
  <li style="height:90px;">six</li>
  <li style="height:50px;">seven</li>
  <li style="height:40px;">eight</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This leaves gaps between columns. Forgot to explicitly mention that in my question, so +1 for providing a working answer for the question as I asked it.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of CSS's [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) and [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) properties (but it will work only with CSS3).

You define your elements in their natural order. However, starting from a given [minimum screen width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), you declare that the boxes must be laid out in an order different from their order in the markup code.

```html
<div id="group1" class="group">
  <div id="one" class="box">1</div>
  <div id="two" class="box">2</div>
</div>
<div id="group2" class="group">
  <div id="three" class="box">3</div>
  <div id="four" class="box">4</div>
</div>
```

```css
/*
 Default style: boxes get full screen width.
*/
.group {
  display: block;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
}

/*
 Big screens: boxes in columns and altered order */
@media all and (min-width: 640px) {
  .group {
    display:flex;
  }

  #two {
    order: 1;
  }

  #one {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

**Example**:
http://codepen.io/abl/pen/rVeXGM

Comment: Oh my god! I didn't know about flexboxes. How wonderful. Thank you, Lord, for making the W3C finally provide this! Alas, I'll have to wait another ten years until IE10 has finally died out...